# How to solve "side effect" with css transorm?

Tags: css

I want to make element "tilt" on my page, to be more precise I have an .svg image (size 100px 100px)  so I have these two css classes, and I have some strange effect, some small white line in upper left corner.

I have tried to add

**-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;**

but it solws problem only in Chrome if I dont hover while page is loading.

```
.tilt {    
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.tilt:hover {    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-500deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    transform: rotate(-50deg);
}
```

Comment: can you post a link that shows the issue?

Comment: ...or better yet, show it right here on the page with a runnable snippet.